# What is the meaning of "(*objx).num;" in the context below

Tags: c++

```
class Demo
{

         int num;
         public:
               Demo setMyValue(Demo *objx) 
               {
                   cout<<"\nEnter a number";
                   cin>>(*objx).num;
                   return *objx;
               }
               ...
};
```

1. What is the meaning of the statement "(*objx).num" in this context?
2. Is it a good programming habit to use this style of taking input in a program?

Comment: Why have you tagged the question with 5 different programming languages, most of which aren't appropriate for your demo code?

Comment: 1) Same as `objx->num`. 2) No, don't use raw pointers in C++.

Comment: @JonSkeet - i was able to grok it and remove the other 4.

Comment: @DanielA.White: Yes, but it's worth pointing out to the OP that he shouldn't do this.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Sometimes raw pointers are necessary since they do not carry the same overhead as smart pointers. It is unlikely that the OP cares about efficiency at this granularity, but raw pointers are certainly not bad practice when used appropriately even though they do leave some extra room for human error.

Comment: @RageD: Some of my advice is not strict in the sense that it's always true, but rather it is of the nature that if you have to ask, then the advice applies, but once you understand where it is no longer true you can safely ignore it. That said, `unique_ptr` has virtually no overhead over a raw pointer and manages the object life time for you.

Answer (score 1):

It is the pointer dereferencing operator.

However, its not a very good idea to do this without checking for `NULL` first.

Answer (score 0):

`*` is the dereferencing operator. You could likewise do `objx->num` (provided that `objx != NULL`). Furthermore, this is fine style. Most people tend to use `objx->num` for readability, but ultimately `(*objx).num` is equivalent. However, in order to return a copy of the object itself, `return *objx` is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Others have defined #1 as the pointer dereferencing operator.

Re #2:  It looks like an attempt at a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) but one that will mislead users and possibly cause a memory leak.

```
Demo a = ...;
Demo b = ...;

a = a.setMyValue(b);  // <- could be a leak
```

Comment: There's no memory leak there, unless `operator=` gives one. Returning a copy of the object is rather odd though.

Comment: @MikeSeymour:  My C++ is pretty weak.  What would happen to the original `a` when `a = a.setMyValue(b)` sets it to `b` (actually changes it to point to `b`)?

Comment: It gets overwritten by the new value, using the same memory. You only get memory leaks if you create an object with `new` and forget to delete it.